# Strange error on IE8 with FB.login()

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, authentication

I've stucked with this problem in IE8. I had a facebook login on my newly deployed site. Everythings seemed fine but FB.login does not work with IE8.

#### HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="" value="Belépés Facebook-kal" class="button buttonBelepesFB left">Belépés Facebook-kal</button>
```

#### Js code:

```
$('.buttonBelepesFB').click(function(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
         if (response.authResponse) 
         {
            window.location.reload(true);
         }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_location,user_birthday,user_likes,publish_stream,read_friendlists'} );
});
```

#### Experienced problem

"An error occurred with Társas Játék. Please try again later."

IE wants to go to this url:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=121508871282409&app_id=121508871282409&client_id=121508871282409&display=popup&locale=hu_HU&origin=1&redirect_uri=%2Fchannel.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df1070f9c58ad265%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df2cd8806c85178&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=email%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_likes%2Cpublish_stream%2Cread_friendlists&sdk=joey

This url fails on all browser.

Thank for your help!